# prevent rails from adding current path url before external js src

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, citrus-pay

I have page where i load js from my payment gateway(citrus) like below

```
<script id=”context” type=”text/javascript” src=”https://sboxcontext.citruspay.com/static/kiwi/app-js/icp.js” />
```

The url for the current page is `http://localhost:3000/listings/10/summary?booking_id=46`

But am getting a 404 error in the console for the below link

```
http://localhost:3000/rooms/10/%E2%80%9Dhttps://sboxcontext.citruspay.com/static/kiwi/app-js/icp.js%E2%80%9D
```

I think the addition of the current url path is the issue here.. Could someone tell me whats wrong here?

Comment: This is due to rails content pipeline, to add external dependencies use the `javascript_include_tag` http://railsapps.github.io/rails-javascript-include-external.html#external

Comment: Thank you..Definitely that seems to be the issue as its now working.. But I cant figure out why some js files loads without these error if I add just in script tag